# How do I lock down outbound firewall access to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, firewall

I'm running a node app which is using the [AWS-SDK module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) to talk to AWS S3.

The infrastructure team want to lock down the firewall but it's not clear what IPs we'll need to lock it down to.

Is there a guide anywhere to how to do this or does anyone have experience of locking this down?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only list that I'm aware of is at the [AWS IP Address Range](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html) page.

You might also want to look at the new [VPC Endpoint for S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/) feature which provides a connection to S3 that doesn't require a gateway or NAT.